# Old iOS app doesn't work on xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have an xcode project created on February 2012. 
I am trying to run it in emulator on Xcode 5 but I got this error: "Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device".

I also tried to change the development release but it doesn't work. Anyway if I click on Product -> Build it says: build Succeeded.

In the emulator I need a code signing ? Because in the project there is a folder cert with various certificate.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the destination you're trying to build for? Is it a simulator, or a device?

Comment: Emulator - iOS Simulator

Comment: What are the architectures you are building for? (e.g. 'armv7')

Comment: whats your deployment target, whats your BaseSDK and whats your architectures & valid architectures (all build settings!)

Comment: Did you try to validate the project settings ?

Comment: @Daij-Djan deployment target: 4.3 (i put 7.0 but nothing) - BaseSDK Latest iOS 7.0 - validate arm64 armv7 armv7s - architectures: standard architectures armv7 armv76

Comment: damn looks good to me

Comment: and when you select a simulator -- iphone 4" iOS 6 - it builds but won't run?

Comment: do you have any non-apple libs/frameworks in your app

Comment: @Daij-Djan The build is ok! When I run on the emulator doesn't work.
Screenshot frameworks: http://imageshack.com/a/img706/8551/somv.png and settings http://imageshack.com/a/img802/7016/iyi3.png thanks

Comment: @Daij-Djan thank you so much! can u give me your e-mail address so we can talk better about it ?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Could be useful use an old emulator or sdk ?

Comment: @Daij-Djan I just sent you an email. Anyway doesn't work with old sdks thx

Comment: @Daij-Djan ready! tell me when. Thanks

Comment: no im not even home tonight. :) just send me the thing. I don't do remote view stuff.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Please can you help me in this weekend ? :)

Answer (score -1):

Go to the project in the Navigator on the left.
Then choose Build Settings and use the search box to search for Architectures.
This'll show you the build architectures setup for the app.

See if you have references to armv6 in there. I'm pretty sure they removed support for below armv7 in Xcode 5.x.

Comment: this is not an answer + building for the simulator is in i386 + building works for some reason